# Python brute force decryption just with ASCII character set from 32-126 (printable)

Tags: python, encryption

> Hi all, having immense trouble here and can't figure out where errors are so seeking assistance. I've > pasted my two (best? closest?) attempts below.
>
> I'm attempting a brute-force approach to decryption, but not using just the usual 26 characters of the > alphabet. The intent is to encapsulate the full set of printable characters from ASCII 32 to ASCII 126.
>
> If I can get this written correctly, it should print out a result at the bottom of this post.
>
> Where am I going wrong?

```
input_string = input('Enter code for decryption: ')
input_list = list(input_string)
shift_value = 0
decryption_index = 0
while shift_value in range(1, 95, 1) : 
    while decryption_index < len(input_list):
        decryption_index = 0
        shifter = (ord(input_list[decryption_index]) - ord(" ") - shift_value) % 95
        chr_decrypt = chr(ord(input_list[decryption_index]) + shift_value)
        input_list[decryption_index] = chr_decryption
        decryption_index += 1
    shift_value -= 1
    input_string = ''.join(input_list)
    print ('Shift value',shift_value,' = Decrypted code:' ,input_string)
```

> &...

```
input_string = input('Please enter code for decryption: ')
input_list = list(input_string)
shift_value = 0
decryption_index = 0


for shift_value in range(1, 95, 1):
    for decryption_index in range(len(input_list)):

        shifting = (ord(input_list[decryption_index]) - ord(" ") - shift_value) % 95
        chr_decryption = chr(shift_value + ord(" "))
        input_list[decryption_index] = chr_decryption
        decryption_index += 1

input_string = ''.join(input_list)

print('Shift value', shift_value, '= Decrypted code:', input_string)
```

> Example intended output:

Shift value 1 = Decrypted code: xjhwjy%xvznwwjq

> ```
>  (through to)
> ```
>
> Shift value 94 = Decrypted code: zljyl{'zx|pyyls
>
> However, I get only:
>
> Shift value 94 = Decrypted code: ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> or a blank.
>
> ## Update as requested; method used to encrypt is:

```
input_string = input("Please enter string to encrypt: ")
    shift_value = int(input("Please enter shift value (1 to 94): "))
    total = ""

    for char in input_string:
        x = ord(char)
        x = x + shift_value

        while x < 32:
            x += 95
        while x > 126:
            x -= 95  

        total += chr(x)

    print("")
    print("Encrypted string:")
    print(total)
```

Comment: can you add some explanation how you are encrypting

Comment: @komatiraju032 - thanks mate - edited with additional code as requested

Answer (score 0):

If you use bruteforce for decryption there is no way you can check which one is correct output. So you need to use`shift_value` to decrypt the string.

```
def decrypt(s, key):
    ans = ''
    for char in s:
        x = (ord(char) - ord(' ') - key) % 95
        ans += chr(x + ord(' '))
    return ans

decrypt('xjhwjy%xvznwwjq', 93) #zljyl{'zx|pyyls
```

And one more thing In your encryption code you are using while loop to change `x` value. Loop is not required for this. You can just use if condition.

```
def encrypt(s, key):
    ans = ''
    for char in s:
        x = ord(char) + key
        if x < 32:
            x += 95
        if x > 126:
            x -= 95
        ans += chr(x)  
    return ans
encrypt("zljyl{'zx|pyyls", 93) #xjhwjy%xvznwwjq
```